# Intellij - how to get rid of extension when auto-import

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea

When I type something like

```
const func = myFuncti..;
```

It will suggest `myFunction()`, and I accept that.

Afterward the import will be like

```
import {myFunction} from '../myFunction.ts`;
```

I want to get rid of the ts, so it becomes

```
import {myFunction} from '../myFunction`;
```

How to do it?

Comment: Read the docs here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-auto-import.html#ws_autoimport_dart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it's a problem of `tsconfig.json`

After changing `allowimportingtsextensions` to `false`, problem sovled

Answer (score 1):

In **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Imports**, try setting the **Use file extension:** to *Never*